# Determine if primary or comparison date range in community connector?

Tags: looker-studio

In a custom connector with date ranges enabled, I want to identify when a request comes in that is intended to return data for the primary date range vs the comparison date range.

My goal in having this identifier is to introduce a control that adds more flexibility for end users than the comparison date range options currently provide, and include that date calculation in the community connector overwriting the provided dates. This would, in effect, give me the ability to allow users to toggle between the adjacent or year over year comparison options.

In my logging, however, I don't see anything I can hinge on to determine whether the request was for the primary or comparison date range. I'm simply provided a date range object:

```
dateRange: { 
    startDate: '2024-02-01', 
    endDate: '2024-02-29' 
}
```

Appreciate any thoughts on achieving this.